# [Solved]SourceTree no changes have been detected, or it is a binary file error

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been facing this error since a few days. sourcetree always said i have a huge number of files changed and i need to commit it before switching to another branch. But I didn't do anything, when i check file that sourcetree said it was change, message show below. I use windows 10.

[image]
[image]

I try a lot of way to fix it but nothing happen, a trick i usually use to solve this error now useless. Help me please!

note: I don't have permission to do anything in the root founder except assigned tasks. thanks!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you say what you have already tried. Also, what were you doing when this issue appeared?

Answer (score -1):

this is solution.

The reason why this error happen is I using Windows OS and my co-worker using Mac OS, encryption is different between 2 OSs and SourceTree cannot compare different.

just commit everything and run again.